# Android: Glide doesn't load image in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-glide

I have a ViewPager with 3 fragments inside. Each fragment is a list to retrieve some exercises from a remote server. The 3 fragments are in order: "explore", "favorite", "recent".

In "explore" list, all images correctly appear. unfortunately in the "favorite" no image appears (just place holder thumbnail).

This is my common adapter:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final T item = getItem(position);
        ....
        Glide.with(getContext())
                .load(UIUtils.getThumbnailImageUrl(item.images))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.default_thumbnail_picture)
                .crossFade()
                .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                        return false;
                    }
                })
                .into(viewHolder.mExerciseImageView);

        return convertView;
   }
```

I put a breakpoint in "onException()" function, and there are several break. Unfortunately, exception is always equal at null...

Could you help me guys?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add this .dontAnimate() 
It will work.